# creating instance of Generic Types class in a not main class

Tags: java, generics, types, static, instance

I have the following Generic type class:

```
public class c1<T> {


public   T a;

public c1(){}

public c1(T a){ 
    this.a=a;
}

public void m( T t){

}}
```

If I create an instance of this class in a non main function(like this) :

```
public class exemplul1 {
c1<Integer> c1=new c1<Integer>();integer
c1<String> c2=new c1<String>();

c1.a=10;
c2.a="Hello";
```

}

I am not able to to create an instance( non static field not able to be referenced from static context).

But if I create an instance in the Main function it is working, no error message.

Can you please tell me why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `c1` defined?  In its own file?

Comment: All classes are in the same package.

Comment: That wasn't quite what I asked; I was asking if it was in its own file or an inner class of some other class.

Comment: As a convention, Java classes start with a Capital Letter.

Comment: `c1.a=10;` is not a valid line of code where you put it. That line can only go in a method, constructor or initialiser.

Comment: (Additionally, you can't just have statements sitting around outside a `{}` block or a declaration; you can't just write `c1.a = 10` in the middle of a class.

Comment: ow, sorry. It has its own file.

Comment: Hint: do not use the same names for different things. "c1" and "c2" are bad names (they dont say anything about the thing that carry the name); and it doesn't help that you have a class named c1; of which you then create two instances that you call c1, c2. That is just confusing everybody. Then: I suggest that you step back. Generics are an **advanced** Java topic. You have trouble getting fundamental basics right. Turn back to tutorials/books for beginners and learn about the basics. Otherwise, nothing will work for you; nothing but frustration; instead of fun learning new things!

Comment: Actually, I am following a course about java and that is how the trainer named them, it was just an example to get the feel what they are and so on. Thanks for your reply.